# Asana API integration using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asana

I am using the Asana API, facing issue while making a API call for getting the new refresh token, Please let me know where I am wrong.

I am making API call through Javascript AJAX.

[app.asana.com/-/oauth_token (POST request)](http://app.asana.com/-/oauth_token%20(POST%20request))

POST parameters

```
{
    "grant_type":"refresh_token",
    "client_id":"",
    "client_secret":"",
    "redirect_uri":"",
    "refresh_token":""
}
```

This is the code I am using:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url : app.asana.com/-/oauth_token, 
    dataType : 'jsonp', 
    method: 'POST', 
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken); 
    }, 
    success : function(result) {}, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){} 
});
```

The returned error I am receiving is:

```
{ 
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type", 
    "error_uri": "asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/…;, 
    "error_description": "The supported grant types are authorization_code and refresh_token." 
}
```

Comment: You should post the code you are using and the error you are receiving.

Comment: This is the code I am using ---> $.ajax( {
    url : app.asana.com/-/oauth_token,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
      },
    success : function(result) {},
   error: function(jqXHR,  textStatus,  errorThrown){}
   });   Error is {
"error": "unsupported_grant_type",
"error_uri": "https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/authentication",
"error_description": "The supported grant types are `authorization_code` and `refresh_token`."
}

Comment: How are you setting the post parameters? Doesn't look like you are sending them.

Answer (score 0):

**Note on OAuth Security Client-Side:**

Keep in mind that AJAX calls are made on the client and that the call you are making requires your `client_secret` which you should treat as a personal password. Making this call from the client exposes that to your user and could cause a security breach.

If you would like to implement OAuth for Asana strictly client-side such as in JavaScript I suggest that you use the implicit grant type. The downside here is that you will not get a refresh token and instead will need to re-authorize your client when your access_token expires.

---

**Addressing The Question:**

When making a call to get a new access token using a refresh token you need  to make a request that looks like the following:

```
     //Request
     POST https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_token

     //POST Parameters
     //Must be either form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded 
     client_id=<client_id>
     client_secret=<client_secret>
     grant_type="refresh_token"
     refresh_token=<refresh_token>
```

Note that the parameters must either be form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded

---

**Official Asana Node Library**

I would also suggest using the official [NodeJS Asana Library](https://github.com/Asana/node-asana/) to implement any of this.

Comment: I went the documents and downloaded the NodeJS Asana Library, which says asana.js not found. Is there any document or link where I will find the whole information without missing a single step.

Comment: You are either not serving the file from your web server correctly or are not including it using the correct path on your client. I updated the README to include grabbing it directly from GitHub releases. Please mark the above answer as accurate if it addresses the question posed.